# Size of device file ( missing in ls -l output )

Tags: command-line, filesystem, udev, ls

When I try to print the device file output shows binary data in hexadecimal format. But upon doing a `ls -l /dev/sda` I get:

```
brw-rw----  1 root disk      8,   0 Jan 29 12:29 /dev/sda
```

I don't understand what is the actual size of the file? What do these numbers mean?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103114/103151

Comment: The `8, 0` has actually nothing to do with file size, but represents the device's **major and minor number**. Read this article to learn more: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2

Comment: To get the physical size of  a block device (disk or partition), use `lsblk`. If you need the exact size in bytes (instead of e.g. "4.8G"), use `lsblk -b`.

Comment: Made a major edit to my answer. Please review !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** : that's how the developers have implemented the `ls.c`. Depending on the filetype, the output string for long option `-l` will be build up differently. GNU documentation fails to mention the format difference(see side note about OpenBSD man page).

**Device files and ls source code**

`/dev/sda` is a block device (explained later in the section). It's different from regular file. `ls.c` builds up the long output string according to what filetype it is working on. As is shown below, **for block devices nothing about size is appended to the output string !**

`ls.c` has the following lines of code:

```c
   3757 static void
   3758 print_long_format (const struct fileinfo *f)
   3759 {

( partially omited )

   3868   if (f->stat_ok
   3869       && (S_ISCHR (f->stat.st_mode) || S_ISBLK (f->stat.st_mode)))
   3870     {
   3871       char majorbuf[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (uintmax_t)];
   3872       char minorbuf[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (uintmax_t)];
   3873       int blanks_width = (file_size_width
   3874                           - (major_device_number_width + 2
   3875                              + minor_device_number_width));
   3876       sprintf (p, "%*s, %*s ",
   3877                major_device_number_width + MAX (0, blanks_width),
   3878                umaxtostr (major (f->stat.st_rdev), majorbuf),
   3879                minor_device_number_width,
   3880                umaxtostr (minor (f->stat.st_rdev), minorbuf));
   3881       p += file_size_width + 1;
   3882     }
   3883   else
   3884     {
   3885       char hbuf[LONGEST_HUMAN_READABLE + 1];
   3886       char const *size =
   3887         (! f->stat_ok
   3888          ? "?"
   3889          : human_readable (unsigned_file_size (f->stat.st_size),
   3890                            hbuf, file_human_output_opts, 1,
   3891                            file_output_block_size));
   3892       int pad;
   3893       for (pad = file_size_width - mbswidth (size, 0); 0 < pad; pad--)
   3894         *p++ = ' ';
   3895       while ((*p++ = *size++))
   3896         continue;
   3897       p[-1] = ' ';
   3898     }
```

Notice that if filetype is `S_ISCHR` (character device, continuous stream of data) or  `S_ISBLK` (block device, random access) the major and minor device numbers are printed to character array `p` (which is essentially a string). *That is the only data that is appended to the output string `p`* . However, when we get to `else` part , `ls` understands that we're working with files *other than block or character devices*. For those files it assigns data stored in size array to the next segments of that `p` size array ( that's `while ((*p++ = *size++))` part).

*The core idea is that ls knows what filetype it's looking at , and builds up output accordingly*

**What are device files anyway?**

Essentially they are references. They are way for applications to deal with actual physical devices and their drivers. For example , `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sr0` (which is CD/DVD drive). Some of the devices are just abstraction. For example, `/dev/zero`, `/dev/null`, and `/dev/random` aren't physical devices. They are ways of interfacing with kernel processes.

*Since they are references, it makes sense that they wouldn't have filesize*. It's possible to know the size of those files that they take up in the `/dev` directory, but they don't correspond to the actual devices they represent !

Thus it is understandable why `ls.c` developers implemented the code that way. The file size of the references is 99.99% of the times not needed for any reason whatsoever.

But block devices, by which we typically mean hard drives and USB drives, are physical devices, with real physical size, so how do we find out that ?

**Finding out the size of actual block devices**

The bellow methods illustrate how one could find out size of a hard/ssd/USB drive referenced by a block device in `/dev/

- `lsblk` or `lsblk /dev/sda`
- `sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda`
- `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `sudo fdisk -l` for all devs
- `sudo parted /dev/sda print` or `sudo parted -l` for all devs
- `awk '{print $1*512}' /sys/class/block/sda/size`
- `awk  '{$3=$3*1024;print}' /proc/partitions` or `awk  '$4 == "sda1" {$3=$3*1024;print}' /proc/partitions` for specific partitions.

**Side notes**

- `/proc/devices` contains list of all major numbers corresponding to the block devices
- `du`, `stat` and `find` commands can show you the size of those references, but not necessary for daily life (if at all)
- There is difference between representation of block devices; some files implement representation blocks of `512` (such as under `/sys` filesystem), while others - [1024](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3132810/3701431). This is a convention in the Unix/Linux world, since that's how actual physical blocks on hard drives are allocated.
- Unlike GNU `ls` documentation, [OpenBSD man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ls.1?query=ls&sec=1) explicitly states: "If the file is a character special or block special file, **the major and minor device numbers for the file are displayed in the size field**." (emphasis added by me)

**References**

- [Understanding /dev and its subdirs and files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18239/85039)
- [Determine the size of a block device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52215/85039)
- [Understanding /dev](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2597?page=0,0)
- [Difference between Device file and device drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101759/85039)
- [Wikipedia:Device file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)
- [Linux Kernel, Chapter 8](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/drivers.html)

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any documentation for why `ls` shows them instead of a plain `0` like `du` or `stat`, but, as Byte Commander says, they are [the major and minor device numbers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt) of that special file. [From the source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n3954):

```c
if (f->stat_ok
  && (S_ISCHR (f->stat.st_mode) || S_ISBLK (f->stat.st_mode)))
{
  char majorbuf[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (uintmax_t)];
  char minorbuf[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (uintmax_t)];
  int blanks_width = (file_size_width
                      - (major_device_number_width + 2
                         + minor_device_number_width));
  sprintf (p, "%*s, %*s ",
           major_device_number_width + MAX (0, blanks_width),
           umaxtostr (major (f->stat.st_rdev), majorbuf),
           minor_device_number_width,
           umaxtostr (minor (f->stat.st_rdev), minorbuf));
  p += file_size_width + 1;
}
```

This code, part of [the `print_long_format()` function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n3844), used when the output format is long (which it is with `-l`), uses the device numbers in place of size for character and block device.

To get the actual size of the device, several methods are listed in [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52215/70524).

Answer (score 3):

It seems you missed the concept of 'everything-is-a-file'.

In the world of UNIX everything (data, devices, sockets, ..) is mapped to a file. Those files have types - in the case of your home directory you will (mostly) find so called *regular files* (text, programs,...).

In contrast to these regular files the /dev-directory holds - implied by the name - device files. Therefore you will find files of type **c**haracter, **b**lock and **p**ipe representing devices, eg. /dev/mem is a file that represents your systems memory, /dev/ttyACM0 can be a serial modem. The link between these (device-)files and the responsible drivers is created using the major and minor numbers as shown by ls (and as explained above).

The size of a device is a device specific attribute and must be queried using device specific tools (as shown in the post above) cause there is no unique way to deal with that attribute (a SSD may have a fixed size - but a serial port can deliver an endless stream of data so there is no fixed size, /dev/null has endless storage :)).

You can read on here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file

Comment: Very good , much improved answer :)